# Oracle query date_add

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have an mysql query(which works fine), when i try to run it in oracle one particular part gives me an error: Can somebody explain/fix why this is happening?

Syntax error expected:
/ 
)
|

```
    timedep >= date_add(now(), INTERVAL -5500 MINUTE) and
    timedep <= date_add(now(), INTERVAL -2 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract the values:

```
      timedep >= current_timestamp - interval '5500' minute
 and  timedep <= current_timestamp - interval '2' minute
```